# Function arguments and parameters not working in vuetify project using "this" keyword?

Tags: function, vue.js, button, click, vuetify.js

I am trying to accomplish something in a vuetify project like the example below, which works with plain html/javascript:

```
<body>
  <button id="anid" onclick="idcheck(this.id)">
  </button
</body>
<script>
  function idcheck(id){
    console.log(id);
  }
</script>
```

But in my vuetify project when I try to accomplish the same kind of thing as seen below, I get a console error of "Cannot read property 'id' of null":

```
<v-btn id="price" flat small @click="idcheck(this.id)">Price</v-btn>

methods: {
  idcheck(id){
    alert(id);
}
```

Is there a way to get the id of the .v-btn element with this sort of method or is this not possible in a vuetify project?

**Edit:** The problem was from me having two functions placed in the button @click, which I unwisely did not state in my example. The accepted answer works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the id of the .v-btn element with this sort of method...

There is, but I wonder what you intend to do with it when you could readily access the object itself (the button) by reference.

```
<v-btn id="price" flat small @click="idcheck">Price</v-btn>
```

```js
{
  // ...

  methods: {
    idcheck(e) {
      const button = e.target;
      const id = button.id; // price

      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have 4 buttons that will ideally gain or lose a class depending on whether they are 'active' or have been clicked. I tried your suggestion but I get "Error in event handler for "click": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of null".

Comment: @MylesMalloy Can you please update your question with the latest attempt? Preferrably with everything needed to verify the issue, since it actually worked for me.

Comment: I tried again this morning and realized the problem was that I had two functions put into the click, which I unwisely left out in my example. So this does work indeed work if it is the only function.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the id in data:

```
<v-btn :id="btnId" flat small @click="idcheck(btnId)">Price</v-btn>


<script>
export default {
  data:()=>{
      btnId:'price'
  },
  methods: {
    idcheck(id){
    alert(id);
  }
}

</script>
```